# Public key encryption for initial challenge-repsonse

Tags: encryption, authentication, key, challenge-response

I understand public key encryption, public key authentication, how digital signatures work and challenge-response authentication, but what confuses me is when they are all combined, and the question can be asked "what processes does the supplicant and verifier go through if public key encryption was used in initial challenge-response authentication?"

Comment: Welcome to Information Security! Please see [ask] and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: If there is a specific problem that you are looking to solve, can you please describe it? Also, adding links to what you've read may help us better understand your question.

Comment: Righto, so I understand public key encryption, public key authentication, how digital signatures work and challenge -response authentication, but what confuses me is when they are all combined, and the question can be asked "what processes does the supplicant and verifier go through if public key encryption was used in initial challenge-response authentication?".

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.

Answer (score 0):

if you're elaborating the key on this very early stage - it's **pre-seed only**, that means that both sides have it before they even decided to start a session and thay *are trusting it*. That's why the licensed CD/DVD media is so hologram-protected e.t.c. : they're carrying a very valuable and vital set of **pre-seeded** keys already in a distro, making MitM's impossible.